# What are the counters in AOE 3?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

Out of the units that can be built in the Barracks, Stables, and Artillery Foundry, which unit is good against which?

I'm talking about these units:

- Hussar
- Dragoon/Ruyter
- Pikeman
- Skirmisher
- Halberdier
- Crossbowman
- Musketeer

I know which units the following are good against, but I don't know which units counter them:

- Grenadier
- Falconet
- Culverin
- Mortar
- Heavy Artiller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Unit                Counters            Countered By
```

#### Light Infantry

```
Crossbowman         Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Ranged Calvary      Melee Calvary

Skirmisher          Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Ranged Calvary      Melee Calvary

Longbowman          Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Ranged Calvary      Melee Calvary

Strelet             Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Ranged Calvary      Melee Calvary

Cassdor             Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Ranged Calvary      Melee Calvary

Abus Gun            Heavy Infantry      Artillery
                    Light Calvary       Melee Calvary
```

#### Heavy Infantry

```
Pikeman             Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Halberdier          Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Musketeer           Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Janisarry           Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Doppelsoldner       Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Rodelero            Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
                    Ranged Calvery      Artillery
                    Buildings

Grenadier           Light Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Melee Calvary
```

#### Melee Calvary

```
Hussar              Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 

Cruissier           Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 

Cossack             Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 

Uhlan               Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 

Lancer              Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 

Oprichnik           Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary 
                    Buildings

Spahi               Light Infantry      Heavy Infantry
                    Artillery           Ranged Calvary
```

#### Ranged Calvary

```
Dragoon             Artillery           Heavy Infantry
                    Melee Calvary       Light Infantry

Calvary Archer      Artillery           Heavy Infantry
                    Melee Calvary       Light Infantry

Ruyter              Artillery           Heavy Infantry
                    Melee Calvary       Light Infantry

War Wagon           Artillery           Heavy Infantry
                    Melee Calvary       Light Infantry
```

#### Artillery

```
Falconet            Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins

Heavy Cannon        Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins

Rocket              Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins

Great Bombard       Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins

Mortar              Buildings           Melee Calvary
                                        Ranged Calvary
                                        Culverins

Culverin            Artillery           Melee Calvary
                                        Ranged Calvary
                                        Culverins

Organ Gun           Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins

Heavy Cannon        Light Infantry      Melee Calvary
                    Heavy Infantry      Ranged Calvary
                    Buildings           Culverins
```

Comment: FYI, it's cavalry, not [Calvary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvary) (a Biblical site), and cuirassier, not cruissier.

Answer (score 3):

I made this simple scheme to help with my games as i play only single player.
[image: Simple scheme]

Comment: No bad, but could use more information.  Can you edit the picture to include the name of the units (or a small picture of them) under the different groups?